# Already logged in but i still get this error "Missing or insufficient permissions."

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know why i get this error: "Missing or insufficient permissions." even i'm already logged in. I followed every tutorial on YouTube but i still get the error.

This is my firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

onAuthStateChanged:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
        //User is signed in.
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        if(user != null) {
            console.log('There is a current user with email', user.email);
            console.log('UID:', user.uid);
        }
    } else {   
        //User is not signed in.
        console.log('Not Logged in')
    }
});
```

firebase login code:

```
 auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
        console.log('Login Successful')
        window.location.assign('/home')
    }).catch(error => {
        let errorCode = error.code;
        let errorMessage = error.message;
        alert(`Error Code: ${errorCode}, Error Message: ${errorMessage}`);
        console.error(error);
    });
```

This is the code in /home

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {firebaseDB, firebaseAdmin} = require('../db');
const firestore = firebaseDB.firestore();

const Subject = require('../models/subject');

router.get('/', async  (req, res) => {
    const teacherRef = [];
    const subjectsArray = [];
    
    console.log(firebaseAdmin.auth().currentUser);
        try {
            //STUB: Getting all ID in Teachers Collection and pushing it in array.
            const dataColRef = await firestore.collection('Teachers').get();
            dataColRef.docs.map(doc => {
                teacherRef.push(doc.id);
            });
            for(let teacherData of teacherRef) {
                const dataSubColRef = await firestore.collection('Teachers').doc(teacherData)
                                                     .collection('HandledSubjects')
                                                     .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
                                                     .limit(10).get();
                dataSubColRef.docs.map(doc => {
                    const subjects = new Subject(
                        doc.id,
                        doc.data().subjectName,
                        doc.data().subCoverImg,
                        doc.data().imgType,
                        doc.data().subjectTeacher
                    );
                    subjectsArray.push(subjects);
                });
            }
            res.render('home', {displaySub: subjectsArray});
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        }
});

module.exports = router;
```

i don't get it when i console.log(firebaseAdmin.auth().currentUser) in server-side, is says "undefined" but in client-side i get the currentUser details.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(firebas.auth().currentUser)` right before your query?

Comment: None of the code you shared reads from Firestore, so it's hard to say where the problem is coming from. But in my experience when the database says you don't have permission, it is quite right about that. So as Dharmaraj commented, you might want to log the current user's UID right before you read from the database.

Comment: @Dharmaraj i tried what u suggested and it says "undefined".

console.log(firebaseAdmin.auth().currentUser);

Comment: @MarcoSardido perhaps the user is not logged in?

Comment: @Dharmaraj but when i console it in the client, i can see the user details

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to access the current user in the Admin SDK. The Firebase Admin SDKs have no concept of a current user, so the `firebaseAdmin.auth().currentUser` call will indeed be undefined.

However: the Admin SDKs run with administrative privileges, which means it is quite unlikely that the permission error comes from there. Are you sure you shouldn't be using/logging `firebaseDB.auth().currentUser`?